# parse html and invoke submit button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing, html-parsing

I am calling a web service method and trying to invoke some action. However, theresponse is 'html'. I need to parse it and invoke the submit button and append the output.

Here's how html (data) looks like:

```
 <form target="_blank" action='../someService.asmx/Action' method="POST">
  <table >      
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Invoke" class="button"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Here's the jquery part:

```
$(data).find('form').find('input[type="submit"]').submit(function(e){
    $('#result').append(output);
    event.preventDefault();                
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three issues, first, the prevent default should be the first line of the handler (My guess), second, you are calling `event.preventDefault` but your handler has a parameter named `e`, and third, you should call the `submit` event on the form, not on the input:

```
data = $.parseHTML(data);
$(data).find('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  
    $('#result').append(output);
});
```

I'm not sure if the `preventDefault` call should always be at the beginning of the handler, but my opinion is that it's easier to know that that handler is preventing the default behavior of the event.

## Edit

After your comments, here is what I believe you want to do:

```
data = $.parseHTML(data);
var $form = $(data).find('form');
$form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').append(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
$form.trigger('submit');
```

Comment: i tried that way earlier, it didn't output anything.

Comment: what is the output variable you are appending to #result?

Comment: well actually i was trying to append the output i get after submit event. however, the submit event is not functioning as i tried to test with alter('test'); and it didn't output anything.

Comment: Well, first, the code is just adding an handler to the submit event, not firing the event. Second, you will have to add an ajax call inside that handler, you wont get the response automagically :) let me do a quick edit for you in my answer.

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: u're awesome! thnks a lot..i was able to append the data. i had to add datatype:'html'.